# how to implement a createDrawerNavigator with native React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I can't implement a DrawerNavigator with react native.
the drawer is displayed well but I have my stack displayed inside. Here is a screenshot and the complete code of my navigation thank you for your help.

https://gist.github.com/darksh3ll/b61820598de91e8addc1a4c20d14a263

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfuHA.png)

Comment: Then where do you expect your "AppStack" to display?

Comment: I must have a problem in my navigation 